# Getting error while trying to erase data from a input textbox using Python selenium

Tags: python, selenium, web

HTML:

```
<div class="emailAttachmentInputMobile">
<input type="text" size="30" maxlength="100" ng-model="emailAttachmentRecipient" class="ng-pristine ng-valid ng-valid-maxlength ng-not-empty ng-touched">
</div>
```

This is my python code:
I have used the following locator strategies:

Using CSS_SELECTOR:

```
WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "div.emailAttachmentInputMobile input.ng-pristine.ng-valid.ng-valid-maxlength.ng-not-empty.ng-touched[ng-model='emailAttachmentRecipient']"))).clear()
```

Using XPATH:

```
WebDriverWait(driver,20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH,"//div[@class='emailAttachmentInputMobile']//input[@class='ng-pristine ng-valid ng-valid-maxlength ng-not-empty ng-touched' and @ng-model='emailAttachmentRecipient']"))).clear()
```

I am getting this error:

> raise TimeoutException(message, screen, stacktrace)
> selenium.common.exceptions.TimeoutException: Message:

Could someone please help me resolve this issue. It already took lot of my time but still not able to fix it

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me (based on the HTML provided in the query):

```
driver.find_element(By.XPATH, "//input[@ng-model='emailAttachmentRecipient']").clear()
```

You may want to extend the XPATH if needed be:

```
"//div[@class='emailAttachmentInputMobile']//input[@ng-model='emailAttachmentRecipient']"
```

Comment: If I use this: "driver.find_element(By.XPATH, "//input[@ng-model='emailAttachmentRecipient']").clear()" 
or
"//div[@class='emailAttachmentInputMobile']//input[@ng-model='emailAttachmentRecipient']"
 I am getting this error
Message: element not interactable

Comment: Could you post more HTML before this line of code, or the website link if possible?

Comment: <div id="emailAttachmentRecipientAreaMobile">
<div class="emailAttachmentLine">
<span class="emailAttachmentLabel">Enter comma separated list of email addresses:</span> 
</div>
<div class="emailAttachmentLine">
<span class="emailAttachmentLabelItalics">(Ex: hygy1@yyy.com, ggyu@vjj.com, yfff@gyy.com)</span> 
</div>
      
<div class="emailAttachmentInputMobile">
<input type="text" size="30" maxlength="100" ng-model="emailAttachmentRecipient" class="ng-pristine ng-valid ng-valid-maxlength ng-not-empty ng-touched">
</div>
</div>

Comment: Even with the above HTML, it works like a charm to me. Tried to first input some email id, and then clear it, and it worked spot on: `x = driver.find_element(By.XPATH, "//div[@class='emailAttachmentInputMobile']//input[@ng-model='emailAttachmentRecipient']")
x.send_keys("yfff@gyy.com")
time.sleep(1)
print("Before clear", x.get_attribute('value'))
x.clear()
print("After clear", x.get_attribute('value'))
time.sleep(3)`.  Output: `Before clear yfff@gyy.com
After clear 
Process finished with exit code 0`.

Comment: Maybe you need some `wait` before coming to this line (since I do not know the whole website behavior leading to this action). If possible share the website link.

Comment: I am still facing element not interactable error
I cannot share my credentials of website that's the issue